# Getting ride estimates and ride changes events in my app

Tags: uber-api

If I use the RideRequestButton in my app (without deep link to Uber app) and I want to get ride estimates the doc says, I call the "requestButton.loadRideInformation();" API. My understanding is this action launches the "RideRequestActivity". My question is if the user changes the start or drop off locations in your Activity or changes the uber product, how will my mobile app get notified on these events and the new estimated price. I see the "RideRequestButtonCallback()", but it does not seem to contain any data. 
Basically, I want to get the location and estimated price information in my mobile app whenever a new ride is requested from my app.

Comment: Help from anyone?

Comment: Please include some code samples. For more info please check documentation for Android: https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk and for iOS: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk